# ActiveModel association and rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

So I have created two models:

`rails g scaffold user name email`

and

`rails g scaffold rental_unit address rooms:integer bathrooms:integer price_cents:integer`

and defined association as follow:

```
class RentalUnit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now, I want to data using rails console as follow:

```
> user = User.new
> user.name = "John Doe"
> user.email = "test@example.com"
> user.save!    
> unit = RentalUnit.new
> unit.address = "abc street"   
> unit.rooms = 4    
> unit.bathrooms = 2
```

but I am unable to associate above record using:

`unit.user = user`

How do I do that in rails console?
What is the better way to define this relationship using generators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build the association as follow:

1. Add `user_id` as integer column in your `rental_units` table
2. add `has_many :rental_units` in your `User` model

Then you can use `unit.user = user` to build the relationship

**Update:**

For adding column in database, you need to add a file in /db/migrate like:

```
class AddUserIdToRentalUnits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :rental_units, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

And run `rake db:migrate` in console

Comment: How to add user_id column in rental_units. should I just edit model file or use scaffold generator?

Comment: Here is the doc you should read to handle database migration: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Comment: `unit.user = User.first
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1`
got this:
`ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `user_id``

Comment: Do you have attribute `user_id` in your `rental_units` table?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to

1. Add reference to rental_unit: use rails command to generate the migration

   ```
   rails g migration AddUserToRentalUnits user:references
   ```

or manually create a migration

```
    class AddUserToRentalUnits < ActiveRecord::Migration
        def change
            add_reference :rental_units, :user, index: true
        end
    end

    rake db:migrate
```

2. Add association in User Model

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :rental_units
    end
```

Then test in console, you should be able to associate it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I got the error on executing db:migrate. uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements::ReferenceDefinition........abstract/schema_statements.rb:802:in `add_reference'

Comment: Could be a type from me. class AddUserToRentalUnits < ActiveRecord::Migration, there was an extra e at the end of class name. But it'll be better see your migration file and models file